# Split values in cell into columns and rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, powerquery, delimiter

Is it possible to split the data within one cell into both cells and rows? I understand with power query you can split into 2 columns using , as delimiter but I wonder If it would also be possible to split this data into rows and columns using a formula. The desired output in reality can be anywhere in the spreadsheet (in reality will be in sheet2).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Power Query you can split into **both** rows and columns as per your question.

- Remove the commas
- Split into rows using `<line feed>` as the delimiter
- Split into columns using the `<space>` as the delimiter

-**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),

    //Remove the extraneous commas
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",",","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column2"}),

    //Split by linefeed into rows
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value", {
            {"Column2", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let
                 itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column2"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column2", type text}}),
    
    //split on the <space> into columns
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column2", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column2.1", "Column2.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Column2.1", type text}, {"Column2.2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this works well although as I have progressed I'm now wondering if its possible to split data in this way with 3+ columns. For example Column 3 would be solvents all listed in the same way as column 2 (i.e. within one cell). However when power query seems to refuse to split in this way. Being new to power query I realise that my initial question was actually quite straightforward and so far havent had to the use M code provided and instead have just used the steps you provided above. In the same way do you think its possible to split 3+ columns?

Comment: @Nick So long as there is some logical and consistent method of accomplishing the split, it should be doable.  Suggest posting it as separate question, along with what you've tried and any problems you run into.  You may need to add an Index column to keep the different rows together.

Comment: Thank you, yes I have posted a new question as I feel it is slightly different. Will keep working on it in the mean time to see if i come up with anything.

Answer (score 2):

Through formulae as per question:

[image]

Formula in `A6`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,REPT(A2:A3&"</s><s>",LEN(B2:B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B3,CHAR(10),""))+1))&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']")
```

Formula in `B6`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,B2:B4),",","")&CHAR(10),"ppm"&CHAR(10)," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0!=0][.!='']")
```

Formula in `C6`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,B2:B4),",","")&CHAR(10),"ppm"&CHAR(10)," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")
```

Though I'd also recommend PowerQuery as per the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66509851/9758194) answer.

Comment: Thank you! I will try the powerquery solution but this is still very useful

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Through Microsoft Excel [Text To Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) function found in Menu Data > Text To Columns.

The ideal text will usually be Mono-spaced(requires monospace font) or delimited by a comma or some other type of delimiter.

Feed good data = better results

Be sure to select the Range of cells you are going to "split apart" BEFORE CLICKING ON Text To Columns.

[image: image1]